# Why does my class run automatically without calling it?

Tags: python

```
name_player = None
health_player = None
inventory_player = []


class engine:

    print name_player
```

I have no idea why this runs without calling it with engine()

Comment: What did you expect? Your print statement isn't really part of the class because it is not in a method. Really, Python should probably refuse to run this.

Comment: Check this out: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects

It helped me understand classes.

Comment: You don't _call_ a class.

Comment: @Selcuk I don't think OP was trying to state that. They're confused why the print statement is being executed before the constructor is called.

Comment: @munk I stand corrected. In this case the answer is that when you instantiate an object using `engine()` your `__init__()` method will be called.

Comment: @jsfan a class is essentially a collection of definitions created by running a sequence of statements underneath the initial declaration. The print statement is most certainly part of this class, given it's indentation level. See https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/grammar.html

Comment: @munk: That's why I feel that it would make more sense for Python to fail on this. If the indentation level puts the code in the class, then the statement makes no sense. Execution at parse-time in classes is rather counter-intuitive IMHO.

Comment: @jsfan execution at parse time is essential in all interpreted languages. How else could you define a class variable or method? `i = 4` and `def foo(self): self.i += 1` are just as much statements as `print "hello world"`

Comment: @jsfan What do you expect python to do? Divide statements into "things that should be evaluated in class definitions" and "other"?

Comment: @munk: I meant parse time as relating to the class. A method of course is parsed but requires a call to be executed.

Comment: @Jon Kiparsky: I think that this should throw and indentation error. But, I do realise that that's an opinion and therefore not everyone will share it.

Comment: @jsfan Indentation looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: This is a philosophical question which could be discussed until the cows come home. So, let's just not...

Comment: This isn't philosophical, we're talking about real engineering constraints on the construction of interpreters based on bnf specified languages.

Comment: @munk Sometimes "philosophy" is just an excuse to stop arguing without conceding the point.

Answer (score 3):

The Python interpreter starts by reading your file, one line at a time.

Step 1:
`name_player = None` adds `name_player : None` to `locals()`

Step 2 and 3 proceed in the same way.

Step 4: `class engine:` Python sees a class and prepares to load the definition into memory. So it's going to read the class and put all of the fields and method definitions into some runtime dictionary probably. In order to do that, it needs to execute the statements in the class.

So normally a class might look like

```
class Foo():
  def my_method():
    return "I'm foo!"
```

This would define a method, and put that definition with the class definition on the heap.

So your definition proceeds as follows. We've started creating the class object and then we come across a statement, so the interpreter executes it. In your case, it's a print statement, so you see it executed.

You'll see now if you call `engine()`, another print won't happen.

What you probably want is to have this statement in a constructor like so:

```
class engine:
    def __init__(self); #__init__() is a constructor in Python
        print name_player
```

For more information about classes in Python, see https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 1):

When you define a class, python evaluates the statements making up the class's definition. If those statements have side effects, for example sending text to the standard output, then that text will get sent.

If you were to instantiate this, by calling `engine()`, you would get back an empty object.